# Passing nil as a UnsafePointer<UInt8>

Tags: swift, swift3, unsafe-pointers

In Swift 2.2, I was able to pass in `nil` as a valid parameter to a function which requires an `UnsafePointer<UInt8>`.  In Swift 3, I can no longer do that:

```
func myFuncThatTakesAPointer(buffer: UnsafePointer<UInt8>, length: Int) { /** **/ }

myFuncThatTakesAPointer(buffer: nil, length: 0)
```

> ```
> Playground execution failed: error: Xcode8Playground-iOS.playground:62:33: error: nil is not compatible with expected argument type 'UnsafePointer<UInt8>'
> myFuncThatTakesAPointer(buffer: nil, length: 0)
>                                 ^
> ```

Am I required to specify the pointer declaration in my function as optional now?

Comment: Please check [this](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0055-optional-unsafe-pointers.md).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Am I required to specify the pointer declaration in my function as optional now?

In a word, yes. From the [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Introduction.html):

> The types UnsafePointer, UnsafeMutablePointer, AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer, OpaquePointer, Selector, and NSZone now represent non-nullable pointers—that is, pointers that are never nil. A nullable pointer is now represented using Optional, for example, `UnsafePointer<Int>?`.

Comment: Thanks matt, congrats on 200k!

Comment: Thanks, but you don't have to put me over the top if you don't want to, I'll get there. :) I realize that my answer is kind of annoying. :)))

Comment: It's all good, I clearly need to spend more time reading the language proposals.

Comment: Actually the release notes doc I pointed you to is better. The language proposals can be really confusing; just because they accepted something does not mean it is implemented in a public release, or that they implemented it the way the the proposal says.

Comment: @matt, better check both docs, 'cos proposal contains motivation for change.